# How can I git push with a specific linux group?

Tags: git

I have a git repository that I use with a few other people. For reasons, github is not an option, so we use a common directory and both clone from there.

The problem here lies in that my default linux group is not the group that the repository is in, so when I push, some group permissions get messed up. The pushed files are just fine ("core.sharedRepository = group" is set in the repository), however the branch heads and paths end up getting my default group. This leads to problems with the others pulling my results if I don't manually change them to the correct group.

Is there a way I can tell git to use the group of the shared repository when I push?

Comment: Use ACLs on the filesystem to force the groups, if possible on the FS you use?

Comment: @Sami That's not bad, but I'm not sure I have that kind of access to the file system. Though if there was a way to force all files created in a directory to have a specific group I may be able to convince someone to change the layout

Comment: Check what FS is in use. Not sure if there's any in use these days that wouldn't support ACL, then it's easy to just say "anything written here will have this group" or at least "anything written here will be accessible by this group." Have used it in many cases and it's a life saver. UGO access definitions don't really cut it usually.

Comment: probably [set-group-id bit](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chown) could help you

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `newgrp` command. <s>My first attempt would be `ggit () { (newgrp gitgroup; git "$@"); }`, that should do it, then you can `ggit push`.</s>

edit: well, my first attempt she no work.  The newgrp command doesn't do any magic, it just fires up a login shell for you. So the command is

```
ggit () { echo git $(git rev-parse --sq-quote "$@") | newgrp gitgroup; }
```

and that works.